# Using RxJava to generate a map where keys are values of a Kotlin enum and map's values come from another RxJava stream

Tags: kotlin, enums, rx-java, rx-java2

### Introduction

Let's say I have a Kotlin enum class:

```
enum class Type {
    ONE,
    TWO,
    THREE,
    FOUR
}
```

and a following data class:

```
data class Item(
    val name: String,
    val type: Type
)
```

Then I have a `Single` that emits a list of `Item`s – can by anything but for example purposes, let's say it looks like that:

```
val itemsSingle = Single.just(listOf(
    Item("A", Type.ONE),
    Item("B", Type.ONE),
    Item("C", Type.TWO),
    Item("D", Type.THREE),
))
```

### Problem

What I'd like to achieve is to have an RxJava stream that will output a map where keys come from `Type` and values are lists of `Item`s matching a given `Type` value (where an undetermined, unsorted list of `Item`s is provided by some other `Single` stream). The signature would be:

```
Single<Map<Type, List<Item>> // or Observable<Map<Type, List<Item>>
```

One additional requirement is that the map's keys should always exhaust all values from `Type` enum even if the `itemsSingle` stream contains no items for some `Type` values (or no items at all). So, for the provided `itemsSingle` example stream the returned map should look like this:

```
{
    ONE:   [ Item(name: "A", type: ONE), Item(name: "B", type: ONE) ],
    TWO:   [ Item(name: "C", type: TWO) ],
    THREE: [ Item(name: "D", type: THREE) ],
    FOUR:  []
}
```

### Attempt

With all the above, I've kinda achieved the desired result with following steps:

1. To satisfy the requirement of exhausting all `Type` enum values I first create a map that has an empty list for all possible `Type` values:

```
val typeValuesMap = Type.values().associate { it to emptyList<Item>() }
val typeValuesMapSingle = Single.just(typeValuesMap)

// result: {ONE=[], TWO=[], THREE=[], FOUR=[]}
```

2. I can get a map that contains items from `itemsSingle` grouped under respective `Type` value keys:

```
val groupedItemsMapSingle = itemsSingle.flattenAsObservable { it }
    .groupBy { it.type }
    .flatMapSingle { it.toList() }
    .toMap { list -> list[0].type } // the list is guaranteed to have at least one item

// result: {ONE=[Item(name=A, type=ONE), Item(name=B, type=ONE)], THREE=[Item(name=D, type=THREE)], TWO=[Item(name=C, type=TWO)]}
```

3. finally I can combine both lists using the combineLatest operator and overwriting initial empty list of items for a given `Type` value **if** `itemsSingle` contained any `Item`s for this `Type` value:

```
Observable.combineLatest(
    typeValuesMapSingle.flattenAsObservable { it.entries },
    groupedItemsMapSingle.flattenAsObservable { it.entries }
) { a, b -> listOf(a, b) }
    .defaultIfEmpty(typeValuesMap.entries.toList()) // in case itemsSingle is empty
    .flatMapIterable { it }
    .collect({mutableMapOf<Type, List<Item>>()}, { a, b -> a[b.key] = b.value})

// result: {FOUR=[], ONE=[Item(name=A, type=ONE), Item(name=B, type=ONE)], THREE=[Item(name=D, type=THREE)], TWO=[Item(name=C, type=TWO)]}
```

### Summary

As you can see, it's quite a lot of code for a seemingly simple operation. So my question is – is there a simpler way to achieve the result I'm after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just merge a map of empty lists with a map of filled lists

```
val result = itemsSingle.map { items->
   Type.values().associateWith { listOf<Item>() } + items.groupBy { it.type }
}
```